# can we customize facebook sdk framework?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

can we customize the login view in facebook sdk framework .Can we put our own button in the place of login button.I got this code from developer.apple.con ->samples->scrumptions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Simply use the facebook's login function on your customized button click.

---

**UPDATE**

```
(IBAction)facebookButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
   [self doLoginAndSwitch];
}

-(void) doLoginAndSwitch
{
    [self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
}

(BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
{
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", nil];

    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions
                      defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                      allowLoginUI:YES
                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) 
                      {
                           [self sessionStateChanged:session
                           state:state
                           error:error];
                      }];

}
```

Comment: but there they are using the buttons from the bundle identifier.But I need to place my button through Xib.? can it possible?

Comment: Yes, you just have to add the login function on your button. I'll update the answer and add the code

Comment: try and implement `doLoginAndSwitch()` in your App Delegate method. PS : you can accept this answer if helped!